# Question content lost when filling out captcha during editing

Tags: bug, edits, captcha

I've just done a load of grammar/layout editing on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11721381/930393)... when I tried to submit I got the "Are you a human" captcha request... not a problem.

What was a problem was that when I entered the captcha information (on the first attempt) it lost the entire body of the question I was editing.  It did NOT revert to the original, it simply lost all question content.

I'm using FireFox 12.0 (yes, I know a bit behind, but it claims all my anti-virus is not compatible with the latest versions).

Comment: Looks like somebody edited that post at about the time you did, it could be that the problem was caused by their edit entering the edit queue / being approved whilst you were filling out the captcha.